# What is/are the difference(s) between "formation of contracts"and "construction of contracts"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, phrase-meaning

I encounter this on the context of:
Uniform Commercial Code (**UCC**) (adopted in all 50 states in the US). This is the phrase:

> The UCC section that is most relevant to due diligence work is the
>   one on sales, which covers **the formation of contracts, construction of contracts,**terms of sale, titles and creditors, good faith, purchases, performance,acceptance and breach, repudiation, and remedies.

Based on **Oxford:**

> Formation:
>   **The action of forming or process of being formed; A group of people or things in a particular arrangement or pattern**

Etym: Late Middle English: from Latin formatio(n-), from formare ‘to form’ (see form). [Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/formation)

Form: **Middle English**: from Old French forme (noun), fo(u)rmer (verb, from Latin formare ‘to form’), both based on Latin forma ‘a mould or form’.[Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/form)

> Construction: **The action of building something, typically a large structure; The creation of an abstract entity**.

**Origin**
Late Middle English: via Old French from Latin constructio(n-), from construere ‘heap together’ 
[Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/construction)

My question:

What are the deeper meanings and different nuances between formation and construction in this context, i.e.: contracts in particular business contracts and legal contracts.?

Based on the dictionary, I take that formation is more to create something from nothing (forming) or creating from zero while construction is more to create something from what is existing (constructing) like a building construction.
So, in conclusion, formation of contracts means freshly-produced contracts with no interferences or external influence except for the legislators while construction of contracts means new contracts built stemming from uncovered terms and conditions that were changed because of different entities or circumstances come into play save for the legislators.

Well, that's my deduction. What do you think?

Thank you very much for your answers/replies! All answers are higly appreciated.

Comment: See the UCC section that is most relevant to due diligence work, which covers the topics for the needed definitions. It is important to know and understand how the terms are **defined in context**.  Definitions of constituent words may not always make up that of a phrase.

Comment: The contextual definitions of the terms are referenced in the cited statement.

Comment: @Kris So, is my deduction correct? which cited statement do you reference it to?

Comment: We are **not** supposed to "deduce" anything. That's the intention of providing the definitions or explanations in the given section. Please refer to the document and use only the definitions or explanations provided therein. Good Luck.

Comment: The UCC section on **sales**. https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/2/ HTH

Comment: One of the senses of *construction*, which can be easily found in readily available dictionaries, is **interpretation**, and that is the sense that the word has here, as in many other law-related contexts.  Generally, sentences like the one quoted are written for the audiences that have a certain background; if one hasn't studied the relevant field, it is unwise to try to guess what such a sentence might mean.

Comment: Why would your trust even one case to the style choices of a generic English forum, please?

In general English, who cares? In legal language, the difference might lose or win your case.

Why not ask the same Question in a legal form?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Formation refers to the initial part of forming a contract, before developing it. First, following an intention to do so, you form a Sales Agreement and then you develop it or construct it by adding the relevant provisions and meeting all the requirements of a Sales contract, i.e. constructing it or piecing the different elements together.

Comment: Please cite your sources.

Comment: @IA12 +1 for your effort and thanks for your reply! I highly appreciate your answer. I'll look into this more thoroughly, as it has apparently different sense to what I thought previously. jsw29 had provided a rough estimate to what this difference might provide.

Comment: As Kris said, can you cite a source for this? I had the impression that "construction" in this context instead referred to how the contract is construed; the relevant [article of the UCC](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/2/article2) has sentences like "Words or conduct relevant to the creation of an express warranty and words or conduct tending to negate or limit warranty **shall be construed** wherever reasonable as consistent with each other;  but subject to Section 2-202, negation or limitation is inoperative to the extent that **such construction** is unreasonable."

Comment: In that sentence, "construction" seems to be closer in meaning to "interpretation" than to "formation" or "piecing together".